# Destination Stream Validation Failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, aws-pinpoint

I've been trying for days, how can I successfully export my Pinpoint Analytics through Kinesis?

I constantly get this error:

> Failed to configure event stream.
>
> Destination stream validation failed.

What does this mean? How can I resolve the issue? Anyone else successfully export analytics from Pinpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out, hopefully it helps someone else out there.

I created a new Kinesis Firehose and tested it out first, making sure the demo data populated in my S3 bucket. After that, I hooked that firehose up to Pinpoint and it successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

(If you're using a Cloudformation stack,) There is also the possibility that Kinesis Firehose is still in a *'booting phase'*, or there is a mistaken arn in the provided `RoleArn`.